# Dismiss a dialog when a thread is done

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm creating a thread in android for a time consuming operation. I want the main screen to show a progress dialog with a message informing that the operation is in progress, but I want that dialog to dismiss once the thread is done. I've tried with join but it locks the thread and doesn't show the dialog. I tried using:

```
dialog.show();
mythread.start();
dialog.dismiss();
```

but then the dialog doesn't show. How can I make that sequence but wait for the thread to end without locking the main thread?

This is as far as I got:

```
public class syncDataElcanPos extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context cont;
    public syncDataElcanPos(Context ctx) {
        cont=ctx;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(cont,cont.getString(R.string.sync), cont.getString(R.string.sync_complete), true);
}

protected Void doInBackground(String... parts) {        
   // blablabla...
   return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... item) {
    pDialog.setProgress(item[0]); // just for possible bar in a future.
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

But when I try to execute it, it gives me an exception: "Unable to add window".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that there is two ways to do it , ( and i prefer the first second one : AsyncTask ) :

**First : you display your `alertDialog` , and then on the method `run()` you should do like this**

```
@override
public void run(){
//the code of your method run 
//....
.
.
.
//at the end of your method run() , dismiss the dialog
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

}
```

**Second : Using an AsyncTask like this :**

```
class AddTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Item, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
//create and display your alert here 
    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Downloading data ...", true);
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    // here is the thread's work ( what is on your method run()
    items = parser.getItems();

    for (Item it : items) {
        publishProgress(it);
    }
    return(null);
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Item... item) {
    adapter.add(item[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    //dismiss the alert here where the thread has finished his work
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

When your thread is done, use the runOnUIThread method to dismiss the dialog.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the on postexecute you can call dismiss

here is an example from other thread

```
class AddTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Item, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        items = parser.getItems();

        for (Item it : items) {
            publishProgress(it);
        }
        return(null);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Item... item) {
        adapter.add(item[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, will try the AsyncTask option and see how it goes...

Comment: How can I add the context on progress dialog? the MyActivity.this is not working for me, says that it can't create with those params, it's taking the activity itself and not the context.

Comment: are you declaring the class AddTask as an InnerClass of your Activity?? if yes ,then it should work , if not , so you should pass the context to your class AddTask

Comment: Yes, I've passed to the task, but I get an exception now, any ideas? the code is on the main question part.

Comment: in your Activity , in the onCreate method , you should instanciate your class syncDataElcanPos like this : syncDataElcanPos instance   = new syncDataElcanPos(this);